# what the order of evaluation of function in printf

Tags: c, printf

The output is not exactly i want.

But if i set another array it works.

```
int n1,n2;
char str[9];
n1 = s_b(argv[1]);
n2 = s_b(argv[2]);

printf("    %s       %s\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
printf("~ : %s       %s \n",b_s(str,~n1),b_s(str,~n2));


int s_b(char *p)
{
    int n = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(p[index] != '\0')
    {
        n <<= 1;
        n |= (p[index++] - '0');
    }

    return n;
}

char *b_s(char *p,int n)
{
    int ind;
    for(ind = 7; ind >= 0 ;ind--)
        {
            p[ind] = (n & 1) + '0';
            n >>= 1;
        }
    p[8] = '\0';

    return p;
}
```

s_b(char *) means string to binary

b_s(char *,int)means binary to string stored in char *

for example

input:

```
   FILENAME 11101110 00010001
```

output:

```
   11101110       00010001

   00010001       00010001
```

but what I expected is :

output:

```
   11101110       00010001

   00010001       11101110
```

Comment: The order of evaluations of function arguments (for `printf` and every other function) is *unspecified*.

Comment: @SteveSummit  alright，and I wonder why it printf like that？

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to the question in your title, the order of evaluations of function arguments (for `printf` and every other function) is *unspecified*.  That means you can't depend on it.  But it turns out that's not your problem here.  (Or see more on this question below.)

The real problem is that you're using one array `str` to hold the results of the two calls to `b_s`, so the second call (whichever one it is) overwrites the first.  So `printf` ends up printing two copies of the same thing.

You can fix this in either of two ways.

**1.** 
Use two arrays:

```
char str1[9], str2[9];

printf("~ : %s       %s \n", b_s(str1,~n1), b_s(str2,~n2));
```

(Perhaps you had discovered this solution already.)

**2.**
Change it to

```
printf("~ : %s       ", b_s(str, ~n1));
printf("%s \n", b_s(str, ~n2));
```

Now you print each string as it's created, before the second call to `b_s()` overwrites it.

---

Addendum:  I may have misunderstood your question "What the order of evaluation of function in printf?".  When you call `printf("%d %d\n", a(), b())`, it is unspecified whether `a()` gets called first or `b()` gets called first.  But it's guaranteed that both `a()` and `b()` will get called before `printf` is called.  Similarly, in your call `printf("%s %s\n", b_s(...), b_s(...))`, *both* calls to `b_s()` happen before `printf` gets called.  That's why the second call to `b_s` overwrites the string created by the first call, such that the same string is printed twice.